# Jenkins doesn't find xcode schemes but schemas are shared

Tags: xcode, jenkins

I am using jenkins 1.572 and Xcode 6

In my jenkins xcode build options I have specified my shared "Xcode Schema File"

**I have already shared the schemes through Xcode - Manage Schemes**
 [image]

When I run jenkins job, it downloads the source code to my local folder, I can run the xcode build command, and it shows my project contains schemes.

[image]

However, when I click off the jenkins job, it shows in the console that my project does't have any schemes. It's odd!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed the issue. I did two things:
1. restart jenkins.
2. Upgrade jenkins to version 1.593